# I have not invited her to the party vs I didn't invite her to the party

Tags: meaning, grammar

I want to know the difference between the following sentences and also want to know which one is correct
If someone asks me at the party that Have you invited her/Did you invite her ? Then which answer will sound good?

1. I have not invited her to the party
2. I didn't invite her to the party

Please someone tell me the differences , thanks

Comment: You need to provide some context of what you're trying to say.  Both sentences are fine.  "Did not" implies that the inviting occurred in the past and you did not do it.  "Have not" implies that the inviting is still ongoing and you have not done it as of now.

Comment: Hello Ali, and welcome to EL&U. This question (about the difference between simple past and present perfect construction) has been asked many, many times here, and also on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Please use the Search Q&A box to the upper right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great deal depends on what you want to say. In general, you would reply to a question using the same construction as the question. So if asked, "Did you invite her to the party?", you would probably respond "I did not invite her," or simply, "I did not." And the same pattern would apply to "Have you invited her?.

However, there is a difference in the two phrases. "I did not invite her" refers to a specific point or period of time in the past, while "I have not invited her" refers to the present. So if asked, "Did you invite her to the party" and you respond, "I have not invited her", the change in tense from past to present would usually suggest that you might invite her in the future (*I have not invited her, but I'm thinking of doing so), or it might serve to emphatically (but implicitly) mean "I have not invited her (and I have no intention of doing so)," The difference would be established by tone, expression and body language.